# Error finding Mono for Android SDK when compiling MonoTouch app using mdtool

Tags: xamarin.ios

I am trying to compile a monotouch application from the command line as part of an automated build. When I run the following command:

```
/Applications/MonoDevelop.app/Contents/MacOS/mdtool -v build "--configuration:Debug:iPhone --project:App.Project" /Users/james/Development/App/App.sln
```

I get the output:

```
MonoDevelop Build Tool
ERROR [2012-10-03 18:03:33Z]: ANDROID: Error finding Mono for Android SDK
System.ArgumentNullException: Argument cannot be null.
Parameter name: path1
  at System.IO.Path.Combine (System.String path1, System.String path2) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Xamarin.AndroidTools.MonoDroidSdkUnix.FindFramework (System.String sdk) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodevelop-lion-monodevelop-3.0.4-branch/ea010826/source/md-addins/MonoDevelop.MonoDroid/external/androidtools/Xamarin.AndroidTools/Sdks/MonoDroidSdkUnix.cs:51 
  at Xamarin.AndroidTools.MonoDroidSdkBase.Initialize (System.String mfaSdkPath, System.String mfaFrameworkPath) [0x0000e] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodevelop-lion-monodevelop-3.0.4-branch/ea010826/source/md-addins/MonoDevelop.MonoDroid/external/androidtools/Xamarin.AndroidTools/Sdks/MonoDroidSdkBase.cs:56 
  at Xamarin.AndroidTools.MonoDroidSdk.Refresh (System.String mfaSdkPath, System.String mfaFrameworkPath) [0x00037] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodevelop-lion-monodevelop-3.0.4-branch/ea010826/source/md-addins/MonoDevelop.MonoDroid/external/androidtools/Xamarin.AndroidTools/MonoDroidSdk.cs:120 
Loading solution: /Users/james/Development/App/App.sln
   Loading solution: /Users/james/Development/App/App.sln
      Loading projects ..
```

Any thoughts on how to get mdtool to compile using MonoTouch rather than MonoDroid?

Additional configuration info:

```
MonoDevelop 3.0.4.7
Runtime:
    Mono 2.10.9 (tarball)
    GTK 2.24.10
    GTK# (2.12.0.0)
    Package version: 210090011
Apple Developer Tools:
     Xcode 4.5 (1839)
     Build 4G182
Monotouch: 6.0.3
Mono for Android: Not Installed
```

Answer (score 2):

You can ignore this error. It always happens, but when you build from within MonoDevelop you don't see it.